# Getting Python error, "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" SOMETIMES

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, nose, python-unittest

Not very new to programming or to python but incredibly green to using pyunit. Need to use it for my new job and I keep getting this error but only sometimes when it is run. My code below.

```
import unittest

from nose_parameterized import parameterized
from CheckFromFile import listFileCheck, RepresentsFloat

testParams = listFileCheck()


class TestSequence(unittest.TestCase):

    @parameterized.expand(testParams)
    def test_sequence(self, name, a, b):
        if RepresentsFloat(a):
            self.assertAlmostEqual(a,b,2)
        else:
            self.assertEqual(a,b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What is happening here is that my test case is pulling a method *listFileCheck* from another class. What it does is it reads values from the serial port *communicating with the control board* and compares them with a calibration file. It puts the control board values in an MD array along with the calibration file values. These values can be either str, int, or float.

I used the test case to compare the values to one another however I keep getting this error but only sometimes. After every 3rd or so run it fails with this error.

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\case.py", line 57, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\case.py", line 574, in run
    testMethod()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Anyone know why I might be getting this error on occasion?

Comment: I could be that the decorator returns a function that that does not match the undecorated function. I would look more into what comes out of `listFileCheck`.

Comment: I've check it, and it always returns the same type list. I think my problem actually was my IDE. I was using pycharm and for some reason it was just running the test case instead of the whole suit so that might have cause the issue?

Comment: Okay :) thanks for the feedback.